# Visual Basic 2010 - Append using Timer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a small program and I ran into a problem. I want to append text to RichTextBox every 1 Timer Tick. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok...handle the Tick() event of the Timer and append your text:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    RichTextBox1.AppendText("Append: " & DateTime.Now & vbCrLf)
End Sub
```